# How to move ImageView and TextView in CardView?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an `ImageView` and `TextView` inside a `CardView`. I can adjust the size of both the `ImageView` and `TextView` but when I try and move either of the 2 inside the XML design window, the top left corner of both doesn't move from the top left corner of the `CardView`, they're just stuck there. Any idea why this happens? I've included an image and my XML code below.

[image: Here is the image showing the problem]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/newsView_container"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_marginBottom="1dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/news_cardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="1dp"
            card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
            card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false">

        <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#406490">

            <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/news_photo"
                    android:layout_width="177dp"
                    android:layout_height="221dp"
                    card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/cast_abc_scrubber_control_off_mtrl_alpha"/>

            <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/news_title"
                    android:layout_width="157dp"
                    android:layout_height="99dp"
                    android:background="#99141414"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
                    android:text="Internet of Things Reaches One Day Volume of $430.00 (XOT) - Modern Readers"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="22sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

When working with `RelativeLayout`, you have basically two different ways to position views inside it.

The first is to use [the attributes available in `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams), such as `centerInParent` in order to center views vertically, horizontally, or both. You can also use attributes like `below` to position views relative to each other.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/news_photo"
    android:layout_width="177dp"
    android:layout_height="221dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

The other is to use margins in order to push views slightly away from the edge of the parent they're fixed to. In your case, with the views stuck to the top left (the default without any of the other attributes specified), you could use top or left margins.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/news_photo"
    android:layout_width="177dp"
    android:layout_height="221dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"/>
```

Comment: The second option worked a bit but i'm trying to be able to move it freely in the xml design window to place it where I want it exaclty, as opposed to hard-coding it's position in.

Comment: Essentially I'm trying to unfix it from the parent

Comment: That is not supported

Answer (score 0):

You can make this possible with `ConstraintLayout`, you can set your `Views` wherever you want and it is so simple and easy. You just have to connect `constraints` with `parent` or with other `Views`.

```
<!-- Your Parent View Start-->
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/news_cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="1dp"
        card_view:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#406490">

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/news_photo"
                android:layout_width="177dp"
                android:layout_height="221dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                card_view:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/news_title"
                android:layout_width="157dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:background="#99141414"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed-light"
                android:text="Internet of Things Reaches One Day Volume of $430.00 (XOT) - Modern Readers"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
<!-- Your Parent View End-->
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you have use relative layout as a parent layout in xml file then  RelativeLayout is a view group that displays child views in relative positions. The position of each view can be specified as relative to sibling elements (such as to the left-of or below another view) or in positions relative to the parent RelativeLayout area (such as aligned to the bottom, left or center).**In relative layout by default views are set in relative layout left top corner. you need to add view relative to anothers views**

for Example

if you want to set image view center in layout then you so add this attribute in child view  **android:layout_centerInParent="true"**

follow these tutorial to design layout in relative layout

[relative layout](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative)

[relative layout](https://abhiandroid.com/ui/relative-layout)